# No value being returned by ‘whoami’ Valence API call

Tags: desire2learn, valence

A client has been developing a c# MVC program to communicate with the D2L platform using the Valence extensibility libraries.  They are able to authenticate their user Id with the platform when registering a new app. However  they are facing a problem with the ‘whoami’ API call.

According to the ‘basic’ program in [Github](https://github.com/Brightspace/valence-sdk-dotnet/tree/master/samples/Basic), there is a session variable called “valenceUserContext” which get values from the following command after authenticating with the platform.

```
Session["valenceUserContext"] = vAppcontext.CreateUserContext( Request.Url, vHost );
```

Unfortunately there were no values returned from the above command (Error is cannot peform binding on a null reference). Do they have to set permissions explicitly for this call in order to get the necessary values returned to the session variable?

Comment: You shouldn't need to set any permissions for the basic sample. Could you use fiddler (as described [here](https://community.brightspace.com/devcop/blog/troubleshooting_your_web_applications_using_a_network_trace~1)) and contact valence@d2l.com? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no mention of user privacy controls for this route in the [documentation](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html). There's an [API Test Tool](https://apitesttool.desire2learnvalence.com/) that can be used to check the Host, Port, App id, and key. If that works for your client, they should double check these variables in their configuration.